# omxplayer and omxplayerd.py - what is wrong with this script?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to get [this little program](https://github.com/mmitch/omxplayer-frontend) working on my Debian Wheezy Raspberry Pi, but I've run into a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to create a simple and easy to use GUI for playing videos - and this is perfect - but while the video files will play, they won't pause, stop, fast-forward, etc.

I think the issue is somewhere here:

```
def omx_send(data):
    subprocess.Popen('echo -n '+data+' >'+re.escape(OMXIN_FILE),shell=True)
    return 1
```

And the part which starts the video player omxplayer in the first place. I have a feeling it's something to do with incorrect handling of `stdout` and `stdin`, but as I said I have no real idea.

```
def omx_play(file):
    #omx_send('q')
    #time.sleep(0.5) #Possibly unneeded - crashing fixed by other means.
    subprocess.Popen('killall omxplayer.bin',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen('clear',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen('omxplayer -o hdmi '+os.path.join(MEDIA_RDIR,re.escape(file))+' <'+re.escape(OMXIN_FILE),shell=True)
    omx_send('.')
    return 1
```

I don't know enough Python to work out what's going on.

As far as I can see, the data is passed correctly to `omx_send`, and when one of the non-working buttons (like pause) is pushed, the terminal reports this:

```
"HTTP/1.1 GET /pause" - 200 OK
```

Any ideas how I would go about fixing this? All I need is for the various little buttons to work and it'd be the perfect bit of easy-to-use software.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the DBUS-based shell-script that comes with omxplayer.

https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/blob/master/dbuscontrol.sh

Comment: Are they executable via the web? I'm looking for a really, really simple solution so anyone connected the the wifi network with a smartphone or tablet can start, stop, pause, etc video on the Pi.

Comment: Ah, no, it isn't. It needs to run locally.